# What is the meaning for GAV in Maven context?

Tags: maven, gradle

Sometimes people say maven GAV, or in the GAV, or GAV artifact in Maven repository.
What is the meaning for GAV in Maven context?

Answer (score 9):

> **REPOSITORY COORDINATES**
>
> Repositories store artifacts using a set of coordinates: *groupId*,
> *artifactId*, *version*, and packaging. The GAV coordinate standard is the foundation for Maven’s ability to manage dependencies.
>
> This set of coordinates is often referred to as a **GAV** coordinate,
> which is short for “*Group, Artifact, Version* coordinate.”

[*Source*](https://dzone.com/refcardz/getting-started-repository#:%7E:text=The%20GAV%20coordinate%20standard%20is,%2C%20Artifact%2C%20Version%20coordinate.%E2%80%9D)